# Sql запрос по двум полям с условием отсутствия значения в первом

Tags: sql, postgresql

Имеется таблица с постами в блоге, где имеется два поля - `publish_time` и `date_posted`, поля `publish_time` могут быть пустыми.
**Вопрос**: Как при помощи sql-запроса упорядочить данные так, чтобы сортировка происходила по полю `publish_time`, а в случае, если у записи оно пустое - по `date_posted`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
order by IFNULL(publish_time,date_posted)
```

Answer (score 1):

Так же нашел решение для данного вопроса с учетом того,что сортировка требуется по  двум и более полям:

```
ORDER BY COALESCE( expr1, expr2, … expr_n )
```